# The values of $\alpha \in [0,1)$ for which the infimum of the set $\{y(x): x\in \mathbb{R}\}\ge 1$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**Question:**

Let $y(x)$ be a solution of ODE $y''-y=0$ with $y(0)=2, y'(0)=2\alpha$, then for the infimum $\{y(x): x\in \mathbb{R}\}\ge 1$, there are  ____  values of $\alpha  \in [0,1)$.

**Attempt:**

We get the general solution of given ODE : $y(x)=c_1 e^x+c_2 e^{-x}$ and using initial conditions, we get: $$ y(x)=(1+\alpha) e^x +(1-\alpha) e^{-x}.$$
Now, using graphing calculator I found that there are  *uncountable* values of such $\alpha$. But I want to show it rigorously . Kindly help. Thanks.

Comment: Are you interested in $\inf \left\{ {x:y(x) \ge 1} \right\}$? What do you mean by a set being $\geq 1$?

Comment: No, question is about the infimum of $y(x)$,i.e. the range not the domain .

Comment: So you are looking for $0 \leq \alpha <1$ for which $\mathop {\inf }\limits_{x \in \mathbb R} y(x) \ge 1$?

Comment: yes, I found that there are uncountable values of such $\alpha$. Am I right? I want to show it mathematically.

Comment: If, for example, $0 \leq \alpha \leq \frac{1}{2}$, then
$$y(x)=2(1−α)\cosh x+2αe^x≥\cosh x≥1$$
for all $x∈\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints: We want $\alpha$ such that $(1+\alpha)e^{x}+ (1-\alpha)e^{-x} \geq 1$ for all $x$. Multiplying by $e^{x}$ and putting $y=e^{x}$ this reduces to $(1+\alpha)y^{2}-y+ (1-\alpha) \geq 0$ for all $y > 0$. If $1+\alpha \leq 0$ we see that LHS tends to $-\infty$ as $y \to \infty$ so we need $\alpha > -1$. Now the condition becomes $y^{2}+sy+t \geq 0$ for all $y >0$ where  $t=\frac {1-\alpha} {1+\alpha}, s=-\frac 1 {1+\alpha}$. The minimum value of $y^{2}+sy+t$ is attained when $y=-\frac s 2$. Can you finish?

Comment: I conclude that all the values of $\alpha \in \{ \frac{e^{-x}}{2} -1 : x\in \mathbb{R} \}$, i.e. $(-1,\infty)$. But in the above question $\alpha \in [0,1)$. Since every interval is uncountable, so there are uncountably many such values of $\alpha$. Am I correct?

Comment: We want the minimum value $\geq 1$. So the answer should not be in terms of $x$. The final answer is $\alpha \in [0,\frac {\sqrt 3} 2]$ which proves that there are uncountably many values of $\alpha$. @Learning