# Find the values of $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $(1+\alpha)e^{x}+ (1-\alpha)e^{-x} \geq 1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Tags: inequality

We need to find the values of $\alpha$ which lie in the interval $[0,1)$ such that $(1+\alpha)e^{x}+ (1-\alpha)e^{-x} \geq 1$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Let $m=e^x$, our inequality becomes $(1+\alpha)m+ (1-\alpha)\frac{1}{m} \geq 1$, this reduces to $m^2-\frac{1}{1+\alpha}m+\frac{1-\alpha}{1+\alpha}\ge 0$. Suppose $p=-\frac{1}{1+\alpha}$ and $q=\frac{1-\alpha}{1+\alpha}$, and take $f(m)=m^2+pm+q$.

Now, we want to find values of $\alpha$ such that $f(m)\ge 0$. We observe that $f$ has minimum at $m=-\frac{p}{2}$. I am stuck here. Please help. If there is any other simple method kindly help. Thanks.

Comment: Why did you open a new question? You could have added these to the original https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4190594

Comment: I was not sure that I could add new question there when I accepted the answer. I tried to solve this on my own but I was wondering if there are simple methods to solve this inequality. Sorry if this irritated you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition on $\alpha $ is $(\frac 1 {2(1+\alpha)} )^{2}-\frac 1 2 (\frac 1 {(1+\alpha)} )^{2}+\frac  {1-\alpha} {1+\alpha} \geq 0$. This is same as $(1+\alpha) (1-\alpha) \geq \frac 1 4$ or $\alpha ^{2} \leq \frac 3  4$. So the answer is $\alpha \in [0, \frac {\sqrt 3} 2]$.

Answer (score 1):

Re-writing gives: $\displaystyle ( 1+a) e^{2x} -e^{x} +( 1-a) \geq 0$

Above is a quadratic inequality in $e^x$ and will hold if we  have: $\displaystyle 1-4\left( 1-a^{2}\right) \leq 0\Longrightarrow -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\le a\leq \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \Longrightarrow a\in [0,\frac {\sqrt 3}2]$